# How to check if a form is being rebuild?

Tags: forms

I want to perform a function if the form is being rebuild.

i.e.

1. If validation fails, or
2. Form is rebuild for any other purpose.

I do not want the function to run in any other case.

How can I do this?

I tried doing this in `form_validation` but it is executed even if form is not rebuild.

Comment: Check `$form_state['rebuild']` maybe?

Comment: @Clive, I want this particular function to execute after the user submits the form and only if the form is being rebuild.

I am not sure if $form_state['rebuild'] would do the trick. Can you confirm?

Comment: @kmdhrm what exactly you want? `$form_state['rebuild']` is `TRUE` only if form is in a state of being rebuild (as to be expected). So just wrap your function in `if` block, testing for rebuild and executing only if true, and that's about it.

Comment: I'm not sure either I'm afraid, probably best to check that variable at various points and see if it has the value you're looking for. I imagine it will be false or not set for the initial form build, no idea if Drupal uses it internally to denote a failed validation though. If you `grep -nr "\$form_state\['rebuild'\]" /path/to/drupal/includes/form.inc` you can find all the places that var is mentioned and used by the core form building logic. The documentation for [`drupal_build_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) looks quite relevant